# AJAX calls in react using JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, reactjs

What is the way call JQuery AJAX in react js?
I used fetch method. Due to environment constraints, I need to change it to JQuery Ajax call. I need json format data from the url. The code I already tried with fetch method is :
(result is the state variable in which I store the json data)

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch(url)
    .then(data => data.json())
    .then(jsonData => {
        console.log(jsonData);
        this.setState({result : jsonData,})
    });
}
```

Comment: I would advise to use axios library instead of jquery: https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios

Comment: can you please tell more?You can use fetch or axios otherwise

Comment: Why do you want to use JQuery? You don't really need it with react

Comment: as others have mentioned, I'd advise you to use axios. But if you are adamant that you need jQuery, then make sure that you have jQuery installed `npm install jquery --save` and imported in your js file `import $ from 'jquery';` then use `componentDidMount() {  $.get('url'); }`

Comment: Yes, It worked, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The common way to make requests in `ReactJS` is use HTTP client named `axios` (https://github.com/axios/axios).

So, your code will looks like:

```
componentDidMount() {
  axios.get(url)
    .then(jsonData => {
      console.log(jsonData);
      this.setState({
        result: jsonData,
      })
    });
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, it will work. But I need to use Jquery ajax calls for server specific scernaio. BTW thanks :)

Comment: What is the reason for preferring axios over jquery?

Comment: Can you explain what you need to do which is exclusive for jQuery?

The reason why you should use `axios` instead of `jQuery` is quite simple - `jQuery` is a massive library, which makes your project depend on. Including it just for use `ajax` calls is redunant. In other cases you should't use it in ReactJS application at all. `Axios` is dedicated HTTP library, easy customizable and has a great API and possibilities (request/response interception, cancel requests, client side support for protecting against XSRF, etc). So, you should include only functionality which you are really need.

Comment: jQuery ajax can do things no other can do. E.g today i needed to use mimeType: "text/plain; charset=x-user-defined" and you can do it only with jQuery ajax